# Why does this Python class have different addresses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers

I made a simple class:

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

then I checked its address with `id`:

```
>>> id(Foo)
4299236488
```

As I was curious, I checked another way:

```
>>> id(Foo())
4332721208
```

Why do they have two different addresses?

Comment: Because `Foo` is the class itself, and `Foo()` is a newly-created *instance* of that class. Why did you think they *would* be the same object?

Comment: Also, you should not think of `id(x)` as returning the address of `x`; `id` give you a (unique) _identity_ that you can compare to other identities. The fact that `id(x)` happens to be the memory address of `x` in CPython is an irrelevant implementation detail that you should ignore.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Simple, but clear explain. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo` is an object and `Foo()` is an instance of the object `Foo`.

```
>>> type(Foo)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> id(Foo)
140710195094936

>>> type(Foo())
<type 'instance'>
>>> id(Foo())
140710195200224
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not check it in another way.

When you call `foo` you just ask where your class is located.

When you called `foo()` you created an instance of you class. And then ask where your instance of your class is located.